# Entity Framework 6- lazy loading expect empty collection but return null (only in test)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, lazy-loading

I use EF6 code first model with lazy loading. I have one normal project (ASP.NET MVC) and one with tests for it. I create in init (drop exsists before) a normal database for testing (no mocking).  I use the same initializer in both project (and for find a problem I try use the same connectionString for creating context).

When I use property witch is collection (data from other table) with no elements, only in normal project ef send sql request (I use SQL Server Profiler to check it), in testing project this property is always null. If collection isn't empty it works correct in both cases.

This is simple version of my code (please tell if you need sth more, I no have a idea where is a mistake):
Data models:

```
public class Story
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public virtual ICollection<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
}

public class Comment
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   [Index("CommentClusteredIndex_StoryId", IsClustered = true)]
   public int StoryId { get; set; }
   public virtual Story Story { get; set; }
}
```

Web.config(project), App.config(tests):

```
<configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="StoriesEntitiesTestContext" connectionString="Data Source=(localdb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=StoriesEntitiesTestDb;Integrated Security=true;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
<entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="v11.0" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
</entityFramework>
```

It's how I used it - code exsist in normal project (this one without tests):

```
public void Method(DbContext context)
{
            DbSet<Story> _dbSet = context.Set<Story>();
            var a = dbSet.First().Comment; //when Comment doesn't have items a is null in testing project and empty collection in normal project
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanna get empty collections instead of nulls, you have to add Constructor to your Entity with collection and in constructor initialize an empty collection.

```
public class Story
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public virtual ICollection<Comment> Comments { get; set; }

   public Story()
   {
       Comments = new List<Comment>();
   }
}
```

Something like that.

Comment: Thanks, it works perfectly :) But can you explain me why in the main project ef return empty collection without constructor?

Answer (score 0):

You need to instantiate your collection in a constructor:

```
public class Story
{
    public Story()
    {
        Comments = new Collection<Comments>();
    }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thank you like above it's a nice solution. But I have the same question do you know why without constructor EF return empty collection in a main project?